# Утопленный текст

Tags: css3, шрифты, css

Как сделать что-то типа [такого текста](http://disqus.com/) (я про текст над кнопками Sign Up и Learn More)?

Comment: Откройте файрбаг и увидите, что это просто картинки.

Comment: Это не картинки.

Comment: посмотрите внимательно, реальный текст в ссылках выталкивается с помощью text-indent

Comment: "(я про текст ___над___ кнопками Sign Up и Learn More)"

Comment: Ну так там у тэга  a 
    background: url("../img/marketing/homepage/cta-buttons.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите свойство `text-shadow`, конкретно в disqus там:

```
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
```

Comment: Спасибо, про это свойство знаю, но не получалось как там сделать. Буду пробовать.

Comment: а чё сложно слямзить "как там" Dragon Fly в Opera или чё там в мозиле и все покажит!